# How do I combine jQuery swipe functionality with a post request?

Tags: php, jquery, html

**Current Situation**

Currently I have created a three column layout for a mobile device.  The data within each column is made up of php which retrieves information from a database and populates each of the columns with posts.  Currently I have implemented buttons within each of the posts which allows the user to successfully move the posts from column to column.

**Question**

What I want to do is instead of having buttons that move the posts I want the user to be able to swipe left and swipe right, having the same functionality that the buttons did.

The current html code for the buttons are as follows

```
<button type='' name='$moveToColumn1' title='Move to Column1'>
<button type='' name='$moveToColumn2' title='Move to Column2'>
<button type='' name='$moveToColumn3' title='Move to Column3'>
```

So basically when the button is pressed I have a php function checking for each of the post requests.  If the button is set some code is performed where the database is updated and the item is moved. The code for that post request is as follows.

```
if(isset($_POST[$moveToColumn1]))
{
}
```

So what I basically need to use a swipe function and for it to perform the code within the post check. Is this possible?

Hope this is clear enough, Thanks!